# get the value by the class name javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm doing some code where i have the following html line

```
 <output id="volumeMin" class="volumeMin3">0.05</output>
```

I need to get the "0.05" and print it using the `class="volumeMin3"` and I need to use `searchEles` to see all elements inside the div. This "output" is inside a div with the rest of other elements

So, I made a `for` loop to see all elements from the div:

```
var searchEles = document.getElementById("divC").children;

for (var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {   //Run all elements on div

    if (searchEles[i].className == "volumeMin3") {  
       alert(inputSlideValue[0].value); //print
    }
}
```

When I was using the debug I noticed that the `searchEles[i].className` didn't match to `volumeMin3`. It appears that `searchEles[i].className` was always empty.

Note: I need to show the results ordered .. if i have an input text and after a checkbox i need to display first the content of the input text and then the value of the checkbox (for that reason i use an array of elements).

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#divC > .volumeMin3')` ?

Comment: but i need to show the results ordered .. if i have a text - combo - check ... i need to show first the text's value and then the combobox and check. if i use a query i will get all the results disordered (i guess) ... for that reason i use a loop

Comment: You would get the values as per the document when you use querySelectorAl. "The DocumentFragment.querySelectorAll() method returns a NodeList of elements within the DocumentFragment (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors."  from MDN documentation. For more info look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use document.getElementsByClassName(). It returns an array so you need to specify what position your looking for:

```
var foo= document.getElementsByClassName("volumeMin3")[0]
alert(foo.value);
```

Comment: There is no other way?Do i really need to stop using the array searchEles?

Comment: Why do you want to use that array? You probably don't have to stop using the array, but, if there is no reason, the above method would be simpler.